# ASP.NET MVC 2 + VS2k10 Empty Start Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have a problem where, on some developer machines, everything resolves correctly and the start page is as expected (/Home/Index), but on other developer machines, it will just render a directory listing of the website root.  When creating a virtual directory, it works, but we would prefer to use the development server initially if possible.

It's worth mentioning the OS we are working with is XP.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does the code build on the other developer machines?

Comment: Yes, like I mentioned, it works on some, but not others.  However, the code is always built on the machine it runs on.

Comment: Are you using IIS or Cassini?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about running your website through IIS or through Visual Studio's built in web server (Cassini)?

It sounds like you are using IIS and it is not configured for running MVC properly but without further information it's hard to say.

I would compare the IIS configuration between a working machine and one that doesn't